# Remove com.browser.player malware

Tags: malware

`com.browser.player` suddenly appeared to my installed application when I connect to a wireless data. It periodically shows advertisement on the screen which is annoying.

I tried to uninstall from **Settings > Applications > Manage applications** but it's still there.

How to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Julius's post on Android Central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/580827-how-uninstall-com-browser-player-application-htc-inspire-4g.html#post4685363), you need to turn off its device administration first.

> Settings -> Security -> Administration, then Deactivate it. Now you can uninstall it.

Assuming you have Samsung device (based on the original revision),

> 1. Press Home key and then tap Menu key > Settings > More.
> 2. Tap Security, and then tap Device administrators.
>
> <sup>From [User Manual for Samsung Galaxy S3 by Sprint](http://eguides.sprint.com/support/eguides/samsunggalaxysiii/index.html#samsung_galaxy_s_iii_ug/device_administration.html)</sup>

For other model, please consult its user manual.

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a rooted phone you can use system app remover like No bloat etc to remove system apps. Try searching for system app removers online. I don't think the option is there for non rooted phones