# How can I stop All Adverticement to my phone?

Tags: ads

seriously i hate advertisements because they disturbing my enjoinment on my phone, even in my other account like facebook, twitter, gmail they suddenly appeared.

Comment: **Note**: the issue is caused by malware (as can be seen from OP's [another post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126512/remove-com-browser-player-malware))

Comment: Very good answers below, but please, try to include screenshots and other info that show your problem instead of focusing on "I hate X". Better to talk about the technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Advertisements are often used by developers to finance their free applications . But if your device shows more advertisements on screen than content it might become a problem.

There are 2 reasons why your android device shows a lot of ads:

1. The individual apps have ads included
2. You have adware on your phone

So first make sure that you don't have any adware/malware installed on your phone. To do this, you can install a trusted adware scanner like [**Malwarebytes Anti-Malware**](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDMQFjACahUKEwj9vYCr19DIAhXMSRoKHTS9BGc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dorg.malwarebytes.antimalware%26hl%3Dde&usg=AFQjCNGy9FRyZCEJBw-8aT9foQY-8TO1XA&cad=rja).

To deactivate inbuild ads you need to root your device.
If your device is rooted, you can install [**AdAway from f-droid**](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway). Note: You don't need to install F-Droid, just download the apk from adaway and install it. (you may need to accept the installation of applications from untrusted sources inside your security settings).
This will block the most common advertisements by altering your hostfile configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Root Access** you can go for software like [AdFree](http://adfree.odiousapps.com/)

AdFree removes most ads in the browser and other apps. Basically It does this by nullifying requests to known host names in the system hosts file.